# Conditions for tilted gas giants

Tags: science-based, astronomy, gas-giants, axial-tilt

I have been working on further refining the solar system that would serve as the setting for my narrative project and in particular I'd like to settle one issue that's been on my mind.

I have been wondering if it were possible to have gas giants (jupiter analogues) with an earth-like axial tilt in the range of 22 to 30 degrees.

And in case it were possible, what are the conditions needed for it to occur realistically?

Comment: Can you clarify why are you asking this on Worldbuilding and not on Astronomy? I see no worldbuilding problem here.

Comment: @L.Dutch Oh right, apologies. How is this now? –

Comment: ??? [Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn) is a gas giant and has an axial tilt of 26°44′. Earth has an axial tilt of 23°34′. Please don't say that there are way too many gas giants in the solar system for you to look up their axial tilts on Wikipedia.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no worldbuilding dependency on the question. In other words, it's a Real Life question that's going to be used in a worldbuilding project, but no rule of the world actually depends on the answer... it's just a Real Life question that should be asked on [astronomy.se]. Also, it took 10 seconds [to find this article about gas giants in our system with conditions you're looking for](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-020-1057-8).

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact We have previously decided that as long as they show a worldbuilding need that we would permit the questions to be asked, even for questions that can be answered by consulting Wikipedia.

Comment: @sphennings What's the worldbuilding need here? There's always been an argument about, "you can't just say, 'I need this for worldbuilding!'" And that's all the OP's done in this case.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact That was my argument then but it didn't stick.

Comment: @sphennings You know, we need a clarification for this, so I've started a [meta discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8488/40609) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt) - Saturn and Neptune both satisfy your criteria (well, except for being smaller than Jupiter and, in the case of Neptune, being more of an ice giant).  That article also links to two ArXiV preprints speaking of simulations for exoplanets.  I also see [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.07615.pdf) finding that CoRoT-2b has an axial obliquity of 45.8 +- 1.4 degrees and HD 149026 b may have one of zero ... neither of those "hot Jupiters" falls within your criteria, but they bracket it and offer hope that data meeting your specifications may be available.

According to [Saillenfest, 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.04104) the axial tilt of Saturn can actually be blamed on ... Titan!  With the rival claimant being Neptune.  Apparently there can be a resonance between the *precession* time of a planet (how long it takes for the North Star to change and return again) and the orbits of other bodies.

Comment: Would you please add [this extra bit](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019DDA....5040005R/abstract) to your answer? It doesn't make sense for me to open another answer just to mention another _possible_ mechanism. Ah, yes, and [this one](https://www.astro.umd.edu/~hamilton/research/reprints/RogHam20.pdf) is another one (reprint) that blames it on spin-orbit resonance.

Answer (score 1):

### A big @$$ impactor

Earth's tilt was caused by a celestial object(moon or planetoid, they're not entirely sure) impacting with it and sending things into a bit of a spin. I'd reckon you'd need a similar thing with a gas giant though perhaps you don't need it to impact so much as grind against it. Think of Saturn giving Jupiter a shy smooch sort of thing.

https://www.inverse.com/article/23062-earth-moon-history-axis-tilt